# Create variable y=1 if row number between 1:200

Tags: r, sorting, row

I've sorted my analysis dataset in descending order by the values of a continuous variable, and would like to create an indicator variable y=1 for the records in the top 200 rows, y=0 otherwise.

My first hack at the problem:

```
train1 <- train1[order(-train1$ALWAMT_FOLLOWING),]
train1$y <- ifelse(train1[1:200,], 1, 0)
```

returns the error:

```
Error in ifelse(train1[1:200, ], 1, 0) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The issue is that the first argument of ifelse() must be logical (i.e. have true / false value), that doesn't seem to be the case here. I won't suggest an answer because it looks like you've got a few which work fine already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ifelse()` is used to return a value based on a test.

Here you just want to give different value depending on the index, not the data, so the easiest is probably:

```
train1$y <- 0
train1[1:min(200, nrow(train1)),]$y <- 1
```

Comment: Great, thank you - and add a comma inside the brackets so we have train1[1:200,]$y <- 1, correct?

Answer (score 6):

Don't bother with `ifelse()` for this.  You can create the vector with `rep()`.

```
train1$y <- rep(1:0, c(200, nrow(train1) - 200))
```

Or you can use the integer representation of a logical vector with the row count.

```
train1$y <- as.integer(seq_len(nrow(train1)) <= 200)
```

Comment: @RichardScriven I get `Error in rep(1:0, c(200, nrow(train1) - 200)) : invalid 'times' argument` when there is less than 200 rows

Comment: @HubertL - I wasn't referring to rows in your answer,.  I was referring to columns, because `data[1:200]` as you had it is subsetting the first 200 columns.  You needed the comma in there is all I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with `ifelse`,

```
rain1$y <- ifelse(order(rain1$ALWAMT_FOLLOWING) <= 200, 1, 0)
```